# multiple peaks fitting using lmfit

Tags: python

I am trying to fit multipe peaks in a spectrum with Gaussian using lmfit but it does not fit properly all the peaks (see figure).

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import Model, GaussianModel

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))  
datax= [ 29.5,  30.5,  31.5,  32.5,  33.5,  34.5,  35.5,  36.5,  37.5,
        38.5,  39.5,  40.5,  41.5,  42.5,  43.5,  44.5,  45.5,  46.5,
        47.5,  48.5,  49.5,  50.5,  51.5,  52.5,  53.5,  54.5,  55.5,
        56.5,  57.5,  58.5,  59.5,  60.5,  61.5,  62.5,  63.5,  64.5,
        65.5,  66.5,  67.5,  68.5,  69.5,  70.5,  71.5,  72.5,  73.5,
        74.5,  75.5,  76.5,  77.5,  78.5,  79.5,  80.5,  81.5,  82.5,
        83.5,  84.5,  85.5,  86.5,  87.5,  88.5,  89.5,  91.5,  92.5,
        93.5,  95.5,  96.5, 100.5]

datay  = [     2,  81057, 586959,  15141,  11441,  10208,  16115,  23656,
        55111,  33352,  14368,   9032,   9810,   9344,  15003,  19679,
        16745,   6492,   5387,   4905,   4644,   5202,   7294,   4828,
         2961,   1900,   1920,   1823,   1737,   1521,   1452,    819,
          481,    438,    505,    409,    299,    230,    199,    113,
          109,     78,     91,     84,     46,     39,     33,     27,
           19,     18,     18,     16,      7,      4,      4,      5,
            2,      3,      2,      4,      1,      2,      1,      1,
            1,      2,      1]
 
plt.plot(datax, datay, '-s', markersize=5)
peak_indices   = [ 2,  8, 15, 22]        # indicess of detected peaks

peakCentroids = [31.5, 37.5, 44.5, 51.5] # detected peaks

model = None 
for i, cen in enumerate(peakCentroids):
    peak = GaussianModel(prefix='p%d_' %(i))
    if model is None:
        model = peak
    else:
        model = model + peak

pars = model.make_params()
stdv = [0.23, 0.75, 0.68]
for i, cen in enumerate(peakCentroids):   # 0.23, 0.75, 0.68
    pars['p%d_center' % (i)].value = cen
    pars['p%d_amplitude' % (i)].value = datay[peak_indices[i]]            # is that a sensible initial value?
    pars['p%d_sigma' % (i)].value = 0.7+i/10 # sigmas are close to 0.7 

output = model.fit(datay, pars, x=datax)
#print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
plt.plot(datax,  output.best_fit, 'r-', lw=2)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xlim(25,  80)
plt.ylim(200, 200000)
plt.show()
```

I could fit the data but the fit must be improved. Any help is highly appreciated...Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY53j.png

Comment: It looks like it is doing a reasonable job of fitting the first 4 peaks.  I think you need to be more specific about how you think the fit would be improved.  Do you want to add more peaks?

Comment: It does not fit well the data between peak1 and peak 2. The fit has a valley between these two peaks

Comment: Well, compared to other peak shapes, Gaussians do go to zero quickly away from their centroids.   Also, you are fitting y(x) but **plotting** log(y) v x, which will greatly emphasize the points with lower intensity.  The region between peaks 1 and 2 is down from more than 5x from peak 2 - that misfit just doesn't make the fit very much worse.   Mostly, I would guess that Peak 1 is not well represented -- you really only have 1 data point for that...